# Choice of a local WAMP server - possibility to add php extensions

Tags: php, wamp

I'm looking for a WAMP distribution for running in my lan (on localhost)

## Now

I'm using usbwebserver, i like it for its simplicity. But this simplicity became a bottleneck when i wanted to add extensions to php. It was (in most cases) not possible.

## Future

I looking for a WAMP-server which is pretty easy to configure but has the abbility to add extra extensions to the php module of WAMP.

Anyone any suggestions? or experience with this subject?

Comment: 99.9% of the time adding extensions is the same for any WAMP,LAMP,MAMP setup. add the extention to `./php/ext` and then edit php.ini or http.conf restart apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, the *best* WAMP-server is [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). Easy to set up, easy to use and just plain awesome.